# CSS dissapears when adding trailing slash to URL

Tags: php, html, css

The problem is that when I add a trailing slash at the address bar url `localhost/register.php/` the CSS dissapears (is not applied anymore). CSS is in a separate file in a separate dir. Here is the structure:

[image: Structure]

CSS is invoked in `header.html` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`
`header.html` is included in `index.php` with `include 'includes/header.html';`

Running apache under Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a trailing slash is added, your browser assumes `register.php` to be another directory, rather than a file. When relative URLs are specified, the external resource will be sought relative to the subdirectory `register.php/` (because of the slash).

**Example**:

- Before adding a slash:
  `css/style.css`  > `http://localhost/css/style.css`
- After adding a slash:
  `css/style.css` > `http://localhost/register.php/css/style.css`.

**Fixing**
To fix this issue, make use of absolute URLs. Either of the following:

- `<link href="/css/style.css" ... />`
- `<link href="http://localhost/css/style.css" ... />`
- `<base href="/register.php" />` (this tag has to be specified within the `<head>`

Comment: Minor elaboration on the `<base>` suggestion: it has to be specified before any relative URLs. If you specify it after one, such as after the `<link>` tag, it'll still fail.

Comment: But if it is treated like a directory why is it still processed as php?

Comment: @abruski Note that I said **"your browser assumes .. "**. Your browser is trying to include the external resources (according to a good guess of the base path), while your server is correctly serving the file.

Comment: Small nit: `<link href="/...` is generally called a _root relative_ path.