# JS & CSS dissapears when adding trailing slash to URL and any word?

Tags: php, html, css, url

I tried to solve it via this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946118/css-dissapears-when-adding-trailing-slash-to-url), but it is not working perfectly, it still writes the URL beside the others like this:

`www.example.com/this.php` and when I click new Page it becomes this: `www.example.com/this.php/that.php`

Is there a solution or Idea?

Comment: The first solution on this link is probably exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework for your design? If yes, then I think you should change your base_url to http://www.example.com. 
Remember, this applies if only u are using a framework like maybe codeigniter.